# Супер простая задача. Превратить числа в отрицательные

Tags: javascript

Я не могу понять в чем ошибка. Я вроде сделал всё правильно. Но задачу не принимают как сделана правильно. Где ошибка?

Задача: В этом простом задании вам дается число, и вы должны сделать его отрицательным. Но, может быть, это число уже отрицательное?
Число уже может быть отрицательным, и в этом случае никаких изменений не требуется.
Ноль (0) не проверяется на наличие какого-либо определенного знака. Отрицательные нули не имеют никакого математического смысла. Я сделал 2 варианта, ни один не подходит.

```
function makeNegative(num) {
if (num >= 0) {return num;} 
else {num * -1;};
return num;
```

```
function makeNegative(num) {
    if (num <= 0) {return num;} 
    else {num => num * -1;}
    return num;
};
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что тут ошибка?

Comment: Вот смотрите, если срабатывает `if` то вы что-то возвращаете, а если `else`?

Comment: Потому что кодвар её не хочет принимать. Я так же пытался через for сделать, но ничего из этого не принимает.  Пишет следующую ошибку :
expected undefined to equal -42
Completed in 2ms
Completed in 2ms
либо 
expected 42 to equal -42
Completed in 2ms
Completed in 2ms

Comment: *"Я сделал 2 варианта"* --- они абсолютно идентичные. И везде неправильно в конце точка с запятой стоИт

Comment: else срабатывает если число меньше или равно 0, то есть, если число отрицательное или 0, тогда срабатывает это num => num * -1; Логические (по идее) оно так и должно работать

Comment: исправил, скопировал не правильно. теперь 2 варианта видно

Comment: А почему вы не пишете `return` при `else`? А при `if` пишете?

Answer (score 1):

Странная конструкция `num => num * -1;` - возвращайте результат.

```js
function makeNegative(num) {
  if (num <= 0) {
    return num;
  } else {
    return num * -1;
  }
};

console.log(makeNegative(10));
console.log(makeNegative(0));
console.log(makeNegative(-4));
```

Ну и функцию можно упростить, отрицательного нуля не существует в js, он будет обычным 0 в любом случае.

```js
function makeNegative(num) {
  return Math.abs(num) * -1;
};

console.log(makeNegative(10));
console.log(makeNegative(0));
console.log(makeNegative(-4));
```

Comment: Vladimir Gonchar твой вариант работает. Буду разбирать и учить. (исправлять свои ошибки)

Comment: Я понял ошибку. Я не возвращал внутри else. Понял. Спасибо парни. Выучу это пожалуй.

Comment: `return (num <= 0) ? num : -1 * num;`

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с `Math.min()`:

```js
function makeNegative(num) {
    return Math.min(num,-num);
}

[1,-5,7,0,14,-100500,7878].forEach(x=>console.info(`${x} >> ${makeNegative(x)}`))
```

С тернарным оператором:

```js
function makeNegative(num) {
    return num<0?num:-num;
}

[1,-5,7,0,14,-100500,7878].forEach(x=>console.info(`${x} >> ${makeNegative(x)}`))
```

C `Math.sign()`:

```js
function makeNegative(num) {
    return -num * Math.sign(num);
}

[1, -5, 7, 0, 14, -100500, 7878].forEach(x => console.info(`${x} >> ${makeNegative(x)}`))
```